# How to select a WinForm DataGridView value, for a specific column, when anywhere along the entire row is clicked?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I've got a simple WinForm app which has a `DataGridView` on it. When the user clicks -anywhere- along the row results, I'm hoping to retrieve the value of the first column (i'll hard code that) which happens to be the ID of that row.

Anyone have any suggestions to how I can do this?

Lets assume the ID of the gridview is `DataGridView1` <-- Bonus points for using the autoegenerated Id's :P

Comment: .. wow. curious to why this gets a downvote...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private void DataGridView1_CellMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{

   var value= DataGridView1[ID_ColumnName.Index,e.RowIndex].Value
}
```

You can also use `CellMouseClick` event handler and use the same code.

I hope you know how to get the event handlers.

Comment: Works great :) I used `CellMouseClick` and yeah, i know how to wire that up. Cheers! (I was looking for some ROW event .. not a cell event).